# Detecting end of method chain in PHP?

Tags: php, fluent-interface, method-chaining

I cannot find a simple example about my question above: how can i detect the end of a method chain?

I'm just looked Zend_Db_Select for example but this one is too complex for this simple question i think.

Is it possible to catch the 'end' of a method chain in PHP?

thanks,
fabrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not possible.

`Zend_Db_Select` does not *detect* the end of the method chain. Every method you chain just returns `$this` and when you stop chaining, you stopped chaining. There is no magic something that says: *Hey, this is the end of the chain*.

Example:

```
$foo = $this->is()->a()->method()->chain();
```

If all methods `return $this`, then `$foo` will contain the result of `chain()`, so `$this` again. You can keep on chaining from there. Of course, the methods will do other things besides returning `$this`, e.g. set internal state - but that's really all there is about [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

If your code needs to know that it has reached the end of a chain, you would have to setup the chain before running it, e.g. [Chain of Responsibility pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility).

Comment: Probably i need to believe you but how can you explain that Zend_Db_Select just doing it?

Comment: Looks like i'm just overlooked it again. So this one (Zend_Db_Select) was the worst example because it doesn't fetch anything it just only builds the query. Am i right?

Comment: Where do you see Zend_Db_Select doing this? As not every Zend_Db_Select method returns $this and the Zend_Db_Select implements __toString() I think you misunderstand what is going on.

Comment: @fabrik Well, yes. More or less. It collects everything you need for creating a SQL query. But there is nothing magical about it.

Comment: Thanks for sorting this out and sorry for the unnecessary question.